# Not able to pass parameters to function in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to Batch file scripting, I need to pass the parameters to a Batch file function, but not able to do so.

The script is shown below. I am trying to replace the **Original** text in **test.txt** to **Updated** text

---

```
set "originalText = Original"
set "updatedText = Updated"

set "sourceLocation = C:\Users\User\Desktop\Temp\Test.txt"
set "targetLocation = C:\Users\User\Desktop\Temp\Test.new"

call:replaceText %originalText% %updatedText% %sourceLocation% %targetLocation%

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:replaceText
SETLOCAL
set "replace = %~1"
set "replaced = %~2"

set "source = %~3"
set "target = %~4"

echo %replace%
echo %replaced%
echo %source%
echo %target%

timeout /t 40

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        (
           for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
              set "line=%%b"
              if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
           )
        ) > %target%
    endlocal

DEL source
REN target source
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: spaces are significant on *both* sides of the `=` in a string `set`, hence you are setting a variable named `originalText[Space]` not `originaltext` - remove the space in every `set` statement

Comment: I sure wish people would read the help and documentation for a command before they come ask questions.